# UsageStats refresh and update time

Tags: android, performance, android-5.0-lollipop, usagestatsmanager

How often are data updated in `UsageStatsManager`? And it is possible to refresh them more often? Because I need to make an application that is tracking other applications usage time and I base on `UsageStatsManager` but it is updated rarely. Sometimes after 20 minutes or even more.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: Events from `queryEvents` are really accurate and up-to-date. We can calculate usage time from them ourselves.